# How to set environment ambient intensity when two scenes are loaded additively in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, urp

I have two scene loaded additively. In each scene, there is an `Environment Lighting Intensity Multiplier` value.

[image]

I have found how to set this value in code, which is `RenderSettings.ambientIntensity`. But it seems that only the first scene's ambient intensity is set when setting this variable.

Which ambient intensity is used when two scenes are loaded addtively? And how do I make sure the `Environment Lighting Intensity Multiplier` is set to the value I want in this situation? Thank you.

I am using URP and Unity2022.1.0f1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, your script that sets the Intensity Multiplier is only on the first scene. You can copy it in the second scene and it should work.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderSettings.html

RenderSettings affects only your active scene.

Comment: Is that mean, if two scenes A and B are loaded additively, all GameObjects in scene A are lit by the RenderSettings of scene A and all GameObjects in scene B are lit by the RenderingSettings of scene B?

Comment: Yea, I think so, I didn't tested it.